# How to separate VueJS Component according to Laravel Blade

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-class-components

I have two blade files

1. generate.blade.php
2. dashboard/index.blade.php

and created a two components

1. ImageuploadComponent (component file)
2. appCurrencies (Vue axios request)

1 -  in app.js file and called those two components in generate.blade.php but when i'm going to dasbhoard/index.blade.php and their i'm getting this error

> app.js:38968 [Vue warn]: Cannot find element: #appUpload

please help me out how may i ignore these error or call these components only in generate.blade.php.

Answer (score 0):

you can add an if statement to check your `#appUpload` actually exist to show your compopnent in `app.js`.

simply add

```
var element =  document.getElementById('#appUpload');
if (typeof(element) != 'undefined' && element != null)
{
  //Your code like 
  const app = new Vue({
              el: '#appUpload',
        });
}
```

With this vue instance will be generated to serve only when you have that id where you want to handle vue components

Comment: thank you very much, but i'm looking for any other solution related to vuejs, like to make a vue http call inside blade or any other way. will be appreciated.

Comment: use axios to call http its just a ajax call.

Comment: can you please gimme some example as i've searched and tried too much but i'm totally confused.